# *.DOC File // One Line Per Page // Date and Day On Each

Tags: microsoft-word, documents

I would like to print a 365 page document.

In the top right hand corner of the **FIRST** page, I would like to have this appear...

```
 2014 - JAN - 01 - WEDS
```

In the top right hand corner of the pages after that, I would like to have this sequence appear...

```
 2014 - JAN - 02 - THUR
 2014 - JAN - 03 - FRI
 2014 - JAN - 04 - SAT
 2014 - JAN - 05 - SUN
 :
 :
 (etc.)
```

...then we get to the next month, which has pages with this in the top corners...

```
 2014 - FEB - 01 - SAT
 2014 - FEB - 02 - SUN
 2014 - FEB - 03 - MON
 2014 - FEB - 04 - TUES
 :
 :
 (etc.)
```

...and so on and so on, until the last page, which would look like this...

```
 2014 - DEC - 31 - WEDS
```

I would like to be able to do the same thing next (which starts on a Thursday).

The next year, which would be a leap year, I would like to be able to accommodate February 29th as well as a different starting day of the week.

My guess is that this would be a full day of typing at the keyboard; with predictable errors from my human hands and mind.

Is there a way to get MS-Word (or one of the 'Libre'Office apps) to generate this sequence for me so that the months, the dates, and the days of the week line up properly ?

I have not found this question either on SuperUser, or doing internet searching.

Does MS-Word (Or Libre'Office) have a macro language that will set this up ?

Is there a sequence of bytes at the end of a text string that tells the app to skip to the next page ? If so I could conceivably do this in my text editor and paste it in.

I trust that I'm making sense with this question. I will be glad to clarify, edit, and re-write this post if it's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the date headers I would use Excel for this.

Cell A1: 2014-01-01

Cell B1: =TEXT(A1,"ddd")

Select cells A1+B1 and drag the bottom-right corner of the selection down to line 365 (or 366 for leap year).

Increase the lower page margin to ~10" to limit to one line per page.

Comment: Trying that, I really want the month in text (e.g., JUN, JUL, AUG, etc.) and the day of the week on it as well.

Comment: How would I put your solution at the top right of the printed page ? How would I print it 365 times ?

Comment: To change the date format: Right click > Format Cell > Number tab > Date

Comment: To move it over you just insert some empty columns on the left. You shouldn't need to print it once; one print should be 365 pages if you set the margins correctly.